# Is Leaflet map setView() inaccurate?

Tags: leaflet

In Leaflet map, I'd expect:

```js
map = L.map(...);
...
var latlng1 = L.latLng(-121.99574947357178, 37.33783464876286);
map.setView(latlng1,12, {animate: false});
var latlng2 = map.getCenter();
if (!_.isEqual(latlng1, latlng2)) {
    console.log("latlng2 should be the same as latlng1!", latlng2);
}
```

But in fact, when running this code, `latlng2` gets assigned with:

```js
-121.99562072753906, 37.33795407160059
```

Looks like this is a precision issue, because the coordinates are indeed close.

My question:
I was hoping to use animation with setView:

```js
map.setView(latlng1,12, {animate: true})
```

As there's no callback which gets invoked when the animation is complete, I was hoping to use `getCenter()` and `_.isEqual` (in the `moveend` event) to compare the requested and actual coordinates. 
Since the actual coordinates are not identical, I could write an `isCloseEnough()` function.
Honestly, I feel my approach is off and so am looking for advice from experienced developers.

Is this a reasonable approach or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

A `isCloseEnough` is the best option here: the nature of [floating point numbers](http://floating-point-gui.de/) is such that absolute comparisons aren't terribly useful if you do any arithmetic with the numbers in between.